# Tuning neural network loss function for space physics

Tags: neural-network, multiclass-classification, loss-function

I am trying to work on neural network classification (with python, Keras) for space physics purposes, where I want to identify specific planetary regions based on multivariate temporal data and multi class classification. Given my objectives, I would like to use a loss function that minimizes such a parameter: `absolute_difference_between_predicted_and_real_class * temporal_distance_to_closest_real_class_change`

More precisely: I have 3 classes corresponding to specific regions around planets, i.e. close planetary environment (class 1), shock (a physical thin boundary at the limit of inner environment; class 2), solar wind (particle flow due to the Sun; class 3).

With classic algorithms I have 2 issues:

1. I get predicted class variations that are physically impossible such as class 3 $\rightarrow$ class 1 or vice-versa, and predicted classes too different from real ones (3 instead of 1 or vice-versa, while 2 instead of 1 or 3 is less problematic for me) ; hence I would like to introduce the `absolute_difference_between_predicted_and_real_class` in the loss function
2. I have significant uncertainties on the exact time of class changes (3 $\rightarrow$ 2, 2$\rightarrow$1 or vice-versa), so that a wrong predicted class transition may not be a problem if not too far from the "real" (but actually always uncertain) transition; hence I would like to introduce the `temporal_distance_to_closest_real_class_change` in the loss function

I know I could use post-treatment but I would prefer, if possible, to introduce these constraints directly inside the loss function. In principle I could write a loss function doing that but I don't know how to cope with the constraints of derivability and others needed for the loss function. I also read a bit on ordinal classification, that would correspond to my issue #1, but not sure not adapted to issue #2. For issue #2 I heard about time warping techniques, but not sure to understand to use that in my case.

Overall I'm a bit lost! Any idea or advice?

Comment: There’s no specific question here. You may have better luck if you ask a direct question. Right now this may be considered too broad to answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the long explanation, maybe this question would be clearer : how to tune a loss function for a multivariate temporal classification (multiclass or binary if easier) that 1) takes into account the absolute difference between classes 2) and/or accepts a time uncertainty (based on the time difference between predicted and real class transitions) instead of taking only sample by sample comparison ?